# View seems to be recursively calling parts of itself, leads to nesting level issue or memory issue

Tags: views

I have a view that is using view content panes, and it is generating the following error:

[image]

I've got a view that looks like this:

[image]

When I show the same map settings as a block, I don't see any issues, but when I try to do the same thing with a content pane, I get this crazy memory issue, or if I'm using xdebug, this Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!issue.

What could be going on? How do I fix this?

Comment: I think XDebug sets the maximun nesting level 100, so use xdebug.max_nesting_level = NEW_LIMIT to increase it.

Comment: Yes, but that won't fix the underlying memory issue/recursion problem.

Comment: Yeah, I extended the nesting limit to 2000, it still reached it.

Comment: Check if your entity calls another entity when is rendered, and the second entity calls a third one and so on. But the strange thing is it works in a block but not ina pane.